# Kafka streams with multiple application instances

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have 2 instances of my application for kafka streams  consuming 2 partitions in a single topic.

will the single partitions data be only in one application or both applications? and Say if one applications instance is down will i have issues. how will interactive queries solve this ?
do i need to use globalktable?

Comment: Kafka streams uses basic kafka concepts for this. 2 instances of stream app means you have 2 consumers for a kafka topic. Here you have 2 partitions . there would be 1-1 mapping for 2 instances.in case 1 goes down your 1 streaming app would be consuming from 2 partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Each kafka stream application instance will be mapped to one or more partition, based on how many partitions the input topics have.

If you run 2 instances for an input topic with 2 partitions, each partition will consume from one partition. If one instance goes down, kafka stream will rebalance the work load on the first instance and it will consumer from both partition.

You can refer the architecture here in detail : https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html 
[image]

Comment: I am talking abt the application where kafka stream is running, since it consumed a single partition data and went down , will the single application running the streams have both the partitions data or how

Comment: Yes, the first instance should repolpulate the state from the changelog topic in case of second instance failure.